# Elegant way of Streaming from OpenCV for C++ beginners?

Tags: c++, opencv, video-streaming

I am captured stream with OpenCV and draw boxes, making marks on the frame and want to re-stream this data that can be seen through browser or any video stream connectable software.

I try to use :

***SERVER****

```
#define BUF_LEN 65540 // Larger than maximum UDP packet size

#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;
#include "config.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2) { // Test for correct number of parameters
        cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <Server Port>" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    unsigned short servPort = atoi(argv[1]); // First arg:  local port

    namedWindow("recv", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    try {
        UDPSocket sock(servPort);

        char buffer[BUF_LEN]; // Buffer for echo string
        int recvMsgSize; // Size of received message
        string sourceAddress; // Address of datagram source
        unsigned short sourcePort; // Port of datagram source

        clock_t last_cycle = clock();

        while (1) {
            // Block until receive message from a client
            do {
                recvMsgSize = sock.recvFrom(buffer, BUF_LEN, sourceAddress, sourcePort);
            } while (recvMsgSize > sizeof(int));
            int total_pack = ((int * ) buffer)[0];

            cout << "expecting length of packs:" << total_pack << endl;
            char * longbuf = new char[PACK_SIZE * total_pack];
            for (int i = 0; i < total_pack; i++) {
                recvMsgSize = sock.recvFrom(buffer, BUF_LEN, sourceAddress, sourcePort);
                if (recvMsgSize != PACK_SIZE) {
                    cerr << "Received unexpected size pack:" << recvMsgSize << endl;
                    continue;
                }
                memcpy( & longbuf[i * PACK_SIZE], buffer, PACK_SIZE);
            }

            cout << "Received packet from " << sourceAddress << ":" << sourcePort << endl;

            Mat rawData = Mat(1, PACK_SIZE * total_pack, CV_8UC1, longbuf);
            Mat frame = imdecode(rawData, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
            if (frame.size().width == 0) {
                cerr << "decode failure!" << endl;
                continue;
            }
            imshow("recv", frame);
            free(longbuf);

            waitKey(1);
            clock_t next_cycle = clock();
            double duration = (next_cycle - last_cycle) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            cout << "\teffective FPS:" << (1 / duration) << " \tkbps:" << (PACK_SIZE * total_pack / duration / 1024 * 8) << endl;

            cout << next_cycle - last_cycle;
            last_cycle = next_cycle;
        }
    } catch (SocketException & e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*****CLIENT******

```
using namespace std;

#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;
#include "config.h"


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    if ((argc < 3) || (argc > 3)) { // Test for correct number of arguments
        cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <Server> <Server Port>\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    string servAddress = argv[1]; // First arg: server address
    unsigned short servPort = Socket::resolveService(argv[2], "udp");

    try {
        UDPSocket sock;
        int jpegqual =  ENCODE_QUALITY; // Compression Parameter

        Mat frame, send;
        vector < uchar > encoded;
        VideoCapture cap("http://ckyxtrm.com:3000/live/muzisyenhakan/29mayismh/178.ts"); // Grab the camera
        namedWindow("send", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        if (!cap.isOpened()) {
            cerr << "OpenCV Failed to open camera";
            exit(1);
        }

        clock_t last_cycle = clock();
        while (1) {
            cap >> frame;
            if(frame.size().width==0)continue;//simple integrity check; skip erroneous data...
            resize(frame, send, Size(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR);
            vector < int > compression_params;
            compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
            compression_params.push_back(jpegqual);

            imencode(".jpg", send, encoded, compression_params);
            imshow("send", send);
            int total_pack = 1 + (encoded.size() - 1) / PACK_SIZE;

            int ibuf[1];
            ibuf[0] = total_pack;
            sock.sendTo(ibuf, sizeof(int), servAddress, servPort);

            for (int i = 0; i < total_pack; i++)
                sock.sendTo( & encoded[i * PACK_SIZE], PACK_SIZE, servAddress, servPort);

//            waitKey(FRAME_INTERVAL);
            waitKey(1);

            clock_t next_cycle = clock();
            double duration = (next_cycle - last_cycle) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            cout << "\teffective FPS:" << (1 / duration) << " \tkbps:" << (PACK_SIZE * total_pack / duration / 1024 * 8) << endl;

            cout << next_cycle - last_cycle;
            last_cycle = next_cycle;
        }
        // Destructor closes the socket

    } catch (SocketException & e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is a slow cant achive more than 10 fps  and seems not will usable for our new direction.

I looked ffmpeg , libsources and didnt find an example to show us a direction to start.

How we can re-stream from the OpenCV with all added overlays etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an uptodate solution here  [MpegServerforRaspi](https://github.com/aanon4/RobotVision)

MJPEG video HTTP streamer for Raspberry Pi

This is a simple MJPEG HTTP video streamer original written to run on the Raspberry Pi. The video input is handled using OpenCV, and the output server based on this web server

It answered my questions..